# Pagecache and dirty pages in paused container

Tags: docker, cgroups

I have a Java application running in Ubuntu 14.04 container. The application relies OS pagecache to speed-up reads and writes. The container is issued a pause command which according to docker documentation triggers a cgroup freezer https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/freezer-subsystem.txt.

What happens to dirty pages and pagecache of the paused container? Are they flushed to disk? Or the whole notion of container-scope pagecache is wrong and dirty pages for all containers are managed at the docker host level?

docker host `free -m`:

```
user@0000 ~ # free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         48295      47026       1269          0         22      45010
-/+ buffers/cache:       1993      46302
Swap:        24559         12      24547
```

container `docker exec f1b free -m`

```
user@0000 ~ # docker exec f1b free -m
             total         used         free       shared      buffers
Mem:         48295        47035         1259            0           22
-/+ buffers:              47013         1282
Swap:        24559           12        24547
```

Once a container is paused, I cannot check memory as seen by the container.

`FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Container f1 is paused, unpause the container before exec`

Comment: Docker docs says that the state of the container is preserved whan container is paused: https://docs.docker.com/terms/container/